# Getting Authorization_RequestDenied (403) on Office 365 Unified API "Get All Groups"

Tags: azure, office365

Trying to use the Unified API to fetch all groups. Using this URL - https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/myorganization/groups but getting 403 - code: "Authorization_RequestDenied", message: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation".

However, it seems like I do have the right permissions - I have Group.Read.All in my token scope which is what's required by this API - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/groups-rest-operations#GetAllGroups).

Could it be because I'm using the Office 365 Unified API as another service (acquiring a separate access token) alongside the old existing code that already uses graph.windows.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the results back if the token has Groups.Read.All scp claim. Make sure you are getting a token for the right resource resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/. If you are unsure you can use this tool http://jwt.calebb.net/ to parse and validate you have the right audience claim.

Comment: I validated my token and saw both the correct resource and scope. The only way I got it working for me is by adding Directory.Read.All to the Office 365 Unified API delegated permissions. As you wrote, this should not be needed and, unfortunately, Directory.Read.All requires admin consent which is a problem for me (it's a muliti-tenant app I'm developing). Could you please check?

Comment: Did you see my comment? It still doesn't work for me:-(. I followed your instructions for validating the scope and it was valid. Yet, only when I added Directory.Read.All to my app I got it to actually work. Am I missing anything?

Comment: We have flagged this as an issue that we are investigating and fixing soon. Right now as you pointed Directory.Read is also required. The desired behavior is that only Groups.Read.All is required. Thank you :)

Comment: Just tried it the other day. It's still not working. Any expected date for the fix?

Answer (score 0):

**Getting groups** (read) worked fine with me in unified API Preview, with the following permissions:

```
Read and write all groups (preview)  
Enable sign-in and read user profile
```

Try adding "Read and write all groups (preview)" not "Read All Groups (Preview)"

However, if you are trying to **create a group**, you will need to also add another directory permission (unfortunately will need admin consent):

```
Read and write directory data
```

these are very weird behaviors from Office365 unified APIs, but we should excuse the APIs as you can see "beta" inside the endpoint URL.

Comment: Thanks but using "Read and write all groups" is not a good solution for me as my app is a read-only app by nature. Asking the user for a write group consent will not be clear and might be perceived as a security issue. I hope MS will solve the issue soon as they've promised - see the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31129194/4920578) to this question.